# What aren't my paths working when I change the way I serve my index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, express, get

I recently decided to update the way I serve my index.html file from

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/..'));
```

to

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../index.html'));
});
```

Both work fine as they both properly serve my index.html file.  However when I switch to using `app.get` ...

I can no longer get my paths to work in my index.html file.

For example, I have a .svg file inside my index.html file that it serves as follows:

```
<img src="dist/images/svg/favicon.svg" width="128" height="128">
```

The request which now fails ( 404 error ) looks like this in the console:

```
http://localhost:3000/dist/images/svg/favicon.svg
```

I have tried adding in the root directory as follows:

```
<img src="ll-server/dist/images/svg/favicon.svg" width="128" height="128">
```

but this does not help - both give 404 errors.

Why is changing the way I serve my index.html file breaking my paths inside the index.html file?

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is changing the way I serve my index.html file breaking my paths inside the index.html file?

`use` runs some code for every URL which starts with the specified path. That code (`static`) looks at the URL, finds a matching file on the specified path, and serves up that file.

`get` runs some for for a specific URL (at least in this case because you haven’t used `*` or a parameter) and that code serves up `index.html` and only `index.html`.

Your images have stopped working because you removed the code which serves up the the HTML AND the images with code which serves up ONLY the HTML.

> How can I fix this?

Put the code back the way it was. The changes you made are not reasonable.

——-

Then fix your security issue.

The directory you are serving your static files from is the parent if the directory your JS module lives in. This means you have given your JS module (and probably all your JS modules) URLs on your webserver.

Don’t expose your server-side business logic.

Change your directory structure. A typical one is:

```
 /            (containing the project)
 /src/        (containing the JS)
 /static/     (containing the static files)
```

Comment: I want access to request and response objects, that is why I'm changing it.  Are you saying it is not possible to server my index.html file using app.get?  What concept am I missing?

Comment: @howard — If you need access to res and req for `/` then **add** a route for `/` and **don’t replace** the existing static middleware. (Make sure you add it before the middleware so that your handler is the first match for the URL).

Comment: Just to re-iterate ... if serve a static HTML file using express.static ... and it has paths to other images in say image tags ... Express/Node will serve them as requested ... however ... if I serve a static HTML file using a GET request ... the server requests will no longer work?

Comment: No.. that isn’t normal.